# Mysql query to count records if data not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have following data values as an example from the table.

```
TId    Date        MID
1     2014-02-01   5
2     2014-03-15   6
3     2014-02-26   5
4     2014-05-03   5
5     2014-04-19   6
```

Now i am trying to show the records group by month and MID if the data doesn't exists on specific month of MID. I tried using UNION to display missing months but not getting expected results like below...

```
MID     Month    count
 5        1        0
 5        2        2
 5        3        0
 5        4        0
 5        5        1
 6        1        0
 6        2        0
 6        3        1
 6        4        1
 6        5        0
```

And here is my query so far... Hope someone can help to get above results.

```
SELECT  Months.id `month` ,
COUNT(my_table.date) `count`
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 ID UNION SELECT 2 ID UNION  SELECT 3 ID UNION SELECT 4 ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 5 ID UNION SELECT 6 ID
 ) Months
 LEFT JOIN my_table on Months.id=month(my_table.date)                       
 GROUP BY Months.id
 ORDER BY Months.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want pairs of months and `MID` that do not exist.  For this, generate all combinations, then use `left join` to match back to them.  Rows that don't match are the ones you want to return:

```
SELECT  m.MID, months.month
FROM (SELECT 1 as month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
     ) Months CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT distinct MID from my_table) m LEFT JOIN
     my_table mt
     ON month(mt.date) = months.month and mt.mid = m.mid
WHERE mt.mid is null;
```

EDIT:

I think the question changed.  To get the count:

```
SELECT m.MID, months.month, count(mt.mid) as cnt
FROM (SELECT 1 as month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
     ) Months CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT distinct MID from my_table) m LEFT JOIN
     my_table mt
     ON month(mt.date) = months.month and mt.mid = m.mid
GROUP m.MID, months.month;
```

Comment: @dCoder . . . The `count()` should not have been there.  It turned the query into an aggregation query, which returns only one row.  It wasn't even syntactically correct, because there was no comma before the expression.

Comment: without aggregation it will not return expected result based on my question. any other solution?